# How To Count Checked CheckBox Inside ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, itemscontrol

I create multiple checkbox using `ItemsControl` in my WPF. But I need to make a limit by 20 for checkbox that can be checked/ticked by user. How do I can check the checked checkbox?

I tried to research this as much as I can, and even binding checkbox to multiple command, but none of it is working. Below is my code to get through the checkbox that were inside the `Itemscontrol`. after, `IsChecked`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ItemsControlUnitPerStrip.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ContentPresenter container = (ContentPresenter)ItemsControlUnitPerStrip.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ItemsControlUnitPerStrip.Items[i]);
    CheckBox checkBoxChecked = container.ContentTemplate.FindName("CheckBoxUnitPerStrip", container) as CheckBox;
    if (checkBoxChecked.IsChecked == true)
    {
        //iOPC.WriteTag(checkBoxChecked.Uid, checkBoxChecked.IsChecked);
    }
}
```

My XAML code

```
 <GroupBox x:Name="GroupBoxSamplingModeStrip" Header="Unit Per Strip" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControlUnitPerStrip"
                      VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding StripRowsCount}"
                                 Columns="{Binding StripColumnsCount}"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxUnitPerStrip"
                                 Uid="{Binding Tag}">
                                    <CheckBox.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip x:Name="TootlTipUnitPerStrip">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                                        </ToolTip>
                                    </CheckBox.ToolTip>
                                </CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </GroupBox>
```

Here the function code on how I generate the checkbox

```
  private void initializeUnitPerStrip()
    {
        unitPerStrip = new List<UtilitiesModel>();
        int totalRow = samplingModeModel.StripRows = 7;
        int totalCol = samplingModeModel.StripColumn = 15;
        int frontOffset = 8;
        int behindOffset = 0;
        for (int c = 1; c < totalCol; c++)
        {
            for (int r = 1; r < totalRow; r++)
            {
                unitPerStrip.Add(new UtilitiesModel
                {
                    Key = $"[{c}, {r}]",
                    Tag = $"{UTAC_Tags.S7Connection}DB{406},X{frontOffset}.{behindOffset}"
                });
            }
        }
        ItemsControlUnitPerStrip.ItemsSource = unitPerStrip;
    }
```

Comment: Does the `ItemsControl` only contains `Checkbox` elements? How do you generate the items, binding to a view model collection? Can you add some more relevant code (details) please?

Comment: @BionicCode yes, its only consist checkbox

Comment: itemControl.Items.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(checkBox => checkBox.IsChecked == true).Count() 

I couldn't understand your code well, i guess this code can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Binding checkbox property with notify property changed events:

```
public class UtilitiesModel : NotifyBase
{
    private bool _IsChecked = false;

    ...
    // Key 
    // Tag 
    ...

    public bool IsChecked 
    { 
      get {return _IsChecked;} 
      set
        {
          _IsChecked = value;
          OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
         }
     }
}
```

For convenience, the part responsible for events is placed in a separate small class:

```
public class NotifyBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged(String info)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML changes:

```
    ..
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxUnitPerStrip"
              Uid="{Binding Tag}"
              IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
              <CheckBox.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip x:Name="TootlTipUnitPerStrip">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
                </ToolTip>
      </CheckBox.ToolTip>
</CheckBox>
..
```

2) Next we shall track events of changing state of checkboxes and add a counter for checked checkboxes;

A slight change in function:

```
private void initializeUnitPerStrip()
        {
           ..
            for (int c = 1; c < totalCol; c++)
            {
                for (int r = 1; r < totalRow; r++)
                {
                    UtilitiesModel item = new UtilitiesModel 
                    {
                        Key = "[{c}, {r}]",
                        Tag = "{UTAC_Tags.S7Connection}DB{406},X{frontOffset}.{behindOffset}"
                    };
                    item.PropertyChanged += PropertyChangedFunc;
                    unitPerStrip.Add(item);
                }
            }
            ItemsControlUnitPerStrip.ItemsSource = unitPerStrip;
        }
```

Add func for checking property changed events:

```
private void PropertyChangedFunc(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            UtilitiesModel obj = sender as UtilitiesModel;
            if(obj==null)return;

            if (e.PropertyName == "IsChecked")
            {
                iCount1 = obj.IsChecked ? iCount1 + 1 : iCount1 - 1;

                if (iCount1 > 19) //Block checking
                {
                    obj.IsChecked = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Where iCount1 - is a counter checked checkboxes, just declare it anywhere, for example in samplingModeModel

Comment: you sir, are beautiful! it works perfectly for my code!

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses MVVM, so the names of your controls in XAML have been removed as they are not needed in MVVM.  Your XAML would look like this:

```
    <Button Content="Count CheckBoxes" Command="{Binding CommandCount}"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>

    <GroupBox Header="Unit Per Strip" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsControl VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                  VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UnitPerStrip}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Rows="{Binding StripRowsCount}"
                             Columns="{Binding StripColumnsCount}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Uid="{Binding Tag}"
                                            IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}">
                            <CheckBox.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                                </ToolTip>
                            </CheckBox.ToolTip>
                        </CheckBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </GroupBox>
```

The only real difference in the XAML is adding the binding to the 'IsChecked' property in the CheckBox, and setting up a binding to a property called 'UnitPerStrip' for the ItemsSource of the ItemsControl.

In the ViewModel then, you need to set up the UnitPerStrip property:

```
    private List<UtilitiesModel> unitPerStrip;
    public List<UtilitiesModel> UnitPerStrip
    {
        get
        {
            return unitPerStrip;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != unitPerStrip)
            {
                unitPerStrip = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("UnitPerStrip");
            }
        }
    }
```

The UtilitiesModel class needs a new property called IsChecked to keep track of when the CheckBox is checked.  That way you don't have to muck about with messy UI code.  It can all be done neatly in the back-end data.

```
public class UtilitiesModel
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

The code for generating the CheckBoxes doesn't change a lot.  You just need to make sure to add in the IsChecked property and then assign the results to the UnitPerStrip property when finished.

```
private void initializeUnitPerStrip()
{
    List<UtilitiesModel> ups = new List<UtilitiesModel>();
    int totalRow = samplingModeModel.StripRows = 7;
    int totalCol = samplingModeModel.StripColumn = 15;
    int frontOffset = 8;
    int behindOffset = 0;
    for (int c = 1; c < totalCol; c++)
    {
        for (int r = 1; r < totalRow; r++)
        {
            ups.Add(new UtilitiesModel
            {
                Key = $"[{c}, {r}]",
                Tag = $"{UTAC_Tags.S7Connection}DB{406},X{frontOffset}.{behindOffset}",
                IsChecked = false;
            });
        }
    }
    UnitPerStrip = ups;
}
```

Then the code to check how many CheckBoxes are checked is very straightforward.  It only examines the data in the ViewModel and never has to worry about messing with any of the messiness of the UI:

```
    private void Count()
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (UtilitiesModel item in UnitPerStrip)
        {
            if (item.IsChecked) count++;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(count.ToString());

    }
```

Comment: Naming controls or UI elements doesn't violate MVVM. MVVM is about separation of UI  from model (business logic). Names can be useful for implementing UI logic in XAML (e.g. Triggers, animations, etc).

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't like to add a special `IsChecked` property to your model you could use a `IValueConverter`.
A property like `IsChecked` is view related and shouldn't be part of the view model (if you can avoid it). When you change the control that binds to the view model you might also need to change this property or rename it (e.g. `IsExpanded` etc.).
I recommend to avoid properties that reflect a visual state inside a view model  in general. Your view model would become bloated if adding properties like `IsVisible`, `IsPressed`, `IsToggled`. This properties rather belong to a `Control`.

The converter (or `DataTrigger`) approach leaves your binding data models unchanged (with data related properties only). To keep the view model clean and free from UI logic like adjusting properties like `IsVisible` or `IsChecked` to reflect e.g. reordering of the collection to the view (e.g. insert or sort operations), all UI logic and visual details like enabling or disabling the controls
should be handled by converters and triggers only:

```
<!-- Decalare the converter and set the MaxCount property -->
<Window.Resources>
  <local:ItemCountToBoolenaConverter x:Key="ItemCountToBoolenaConverter" 
                                     MaxCount="20" />
</Window.Resources>

<! -- The actual DataTemplate -->
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxUnitPerStrip"
              IsEnabled="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}, Converter={StaticResource ItemCountToBoolenaConverter}}">
      <CheckBox.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip x:Name="TootlTipUnitPerStrip">
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" />
        </ToolTip>
      </CheckBox.ToolTip>
    </CheckBox>
  </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

The `ItemCountToBoolenaConverter`:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(ListBoxItem), typeof(bool))]
class ItemCountToBoolenaConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public int MaxCount { get; set; }

  #region Implementation of IValueConverter

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value is ListBoxItem itemContainer && TryFindParentElement(itemContainer, out ItemsControl parentItemsControl))

    {
      return parentItemsControl.Items.IndexOf(itemContainer.Content) < this.MaxCount;
    }

    return Binding.DoNothing;
  }

  /// <inheritdoc />
  public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }

  #endregion

  // Consider to make this an Extension Method for DependencyObject
  private bool TryFindVisualParent<TParent>(DependencyObject child, out TParent resultElement) where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (child == null)
      return false;

    DependencyObject parentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);         

    if (parentElement is TParent)
    {
      resultElement = parentElement as TParent;
      return true;
    }

     return TryFindVisualParent(parentElement, out resultElement);
  }
}
```